# prove that the operator is compact.

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space over $\mathbb C$, and $\{f_j\}$ a orthonormal set in $H$. Let $t_j\in \mathbb C$ such that $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to \infty} t_j =0$ i.e $(t_j)_{j\in \mathbb N}\in c_0$. Show that the operator $T:H\to H$ defined by:

$Tx=\sum t_j (f_j \cdot x)f_j$ is compact.

It's easy to prove if $X$ is a reflexive space, then an operator in compact if and only if carries weakly convergent into norm convergent sequences(and it's enough the case weakly convergent to zero). If $H$ is a Hilbert space, then it's reflexive.

Let $x_j \to 0$ weakly. I don't know how to do this problem, because I can bound $||Tx||\le ||x|| \sum |t_j|$ but the right side could be infinite.

Comment: What does $X$ stand for?

Comment: Don't bother with weak convergence. Showing that $(Tx_n)$ contains a convergent subsequence for every sequence $(x_n)$ in the unit ball is straightforward enough.

Comment: It is also easy to prove that this is the norm limit of a sequence of finite rank operators. By the way, your operator is diagonal.

Comment: @DanielFischer I want to know how do I find the convergent subsequence, I don't know how to prove that the convergence of those finite rank operators is uniform .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For each $n\in \mathbb{N}$, define
$$
T_n(x) = \sum_{j=1}^n t_j (f_j\cdot x)f_j
$$
Then, $T_n$ is finite rank, and hence compact. Now consider
$$
\|T(x)-T_n(x)\| \leq \sum_{j=n+1}^{\infty} |t_j||(f_j\cdot x)| \leq u_n\|x\|
$$
by Bessel's inequality, where
$$
u_n = \sup_{j\geq n} |t_j|
$$
Now,
$$
\lim u_n = \limsup |t_n| = 0
$$
and hence for $\epsilon > 0$, there is $N_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $u_n < \epsilon$ for all $n\geq N_0$, in which case
$$
\|T-T_n\| < \epsilon \quad\forall n\geq N_0
$$
Hence, $T$ is the limit of finite rank operators, and is hence compact.

Comment: How is Bessel's inequality used here? It usually involves sums of squares.

Comment: @Ulrik maybe he means Cauchy Schwarz?